# Filemaker or applescript calculation to identify and add proper file extensions when exporting containers

Tags: applescript, acrobat, filemaker

I have a variety of mixed media stored in container fields that I am trying to export and open (primarily with adobe Acrobat) I am running into a problem when exporting these documents because many either do not have file extensions or when we rename them upon export and add an extension like .PDF it is often incompatible with the actual file type creating an error message from acrobat when trying to open... Is there a function, plugin or calculation that we can use on the export to properly identify the file type and add the extension on the end of the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the name extension of images which not have file extension:

You can use the unix command "file" to get the type of the image (work also on PDF's document).

Here is an example:

```
set myFolder to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Print:"
set myfiles to list folder myFolder without invisibles
repeat with f in myfiles
    set tFile to myFolder & f
    set na_Ext to name extension of (info for file tFile)

    if na_Ext is missing value then -- no name extension
        set r to do shell script "/usr/bin/file " & quoted form of POSIX path of tFile -- get the type of this image
        if "PDF document" is in r then
            set na_Ext to ".pdf"
        else if "PNG image data" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "png"
        else if "TIFF image data" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "tiff"
        else if "JPEG image data" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "jpg"
        else if "JPEG 2000 image data" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "jp2"
        else if "Adobe Photoshop Image" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "psd"
        else if "PC bitmap" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "bmp"
        else if "GIF image data" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "gif"
        else if "SGI image data" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "sgi"
        else if "Targa image data" is in r then
            set na_Ext to "tga"
        end if

        if na_Ext is not missing value then
            tell application "Finder" to set name extension of file tFile to na_Ext -- set the name extension of this file
        end if -- else the type of this image is not in this script
    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name extension property:

```
tell application "Finder" to set nameEx to name extension of (choose file)
```

EDIT

This will give you the path and the name extension of each file...

```
set myFolder to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Print:"

tell application "Finder"
    set myfiles to files of folder myFolder as alias list
    repeat with myfile in myfiles
        set mycurrentfile to myfile as text
        --my batchprint(mycurrentfile) 
        set nameEx to name extension of myfile
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Couldn't seem to get this command to work.. Keeps coming back with an error and says it can't get extension...???

Comment: `set myFolder to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Print:"  

set myfiles to list folder myFolder without invisibles  

repeat with myfile in myfiles  
 
 set mycurrentfile to ((myFolder as string) & (myfile as string)) as string  
 batchprint(mycurrentfile)  
 
 tell application "Finder" to set nameEx to name extension of myfile  
 
end repeat`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Your code edit worked to identify the extension on files that had extensions already (meaning JPG who's extension was invisible due to finder preferences) and the extension appeared in the applescript result window but did not append the actual file with the extension.. Further when I used the got info command and removed the .jpg extension from the file and tested the script again, it could not determine the proper extension returning ""